# How to stop animator

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, 2d

I want to stop to animation of a spirit when I remove my finger from the D key,The animator is the one that made automatically when you use image like that [image: The Picture!]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public GameObject main_camera;
    void Start () {
        main_camera = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 1*Time.deltaTime); 
            main_camera.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 1*Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.D)) {
            //WANT ANIMATION TO STOP
            Animator.speed(0);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the speed of the Animation component to 0.
You will need to provide the animation clip name as well.

Here is an example:

```
 Animation animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
 string animationClipName = "1";

 animation[animationClipName].speed = 0;
```

Comment: Care to explain what that code is doing, or how it solves the OP's problem? Code-only answers are considered low quality.

Comment: Don't you worry...I'll explain tonight :)